# ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type

Tags: python, pandas

I've been using `mplsoccer` library and `statsbombpy` libraries for a while now with success.
Recently, I've tried to use it again with this code (not fully reproducible due to it being behind a paid api).

```
!pip install mplsoccer
import pandas as pd
import requests
from mplsoccer.statsbomb import read_event
username = creds['user']
password = creds['passwd']
auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
URL = 'https://data.statsbombservices.com/api/v5/events/18241'
response = requests.get(URL, auth = auth)
df_dict = read_event(response)
```

and I'm now starting to get the ValueError of invalid file path or buffer type. I contacted the owner of mplsoccer and asked him about it, and he said it wasn't a reproducible error for him, but it looks like my pandas is having trouble reading it.

`response` is returning exactly what it should be, it just fails with the below error code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-9be43ec4f519> in <module>
      6 URL = 'https://data.statsbombservices.com/api/v5/events/7430'
      7 response = requests.get(URL, auth=auth)
----> 8 df_dict = read_event(response)

E:\py\lib\site-packages\mplsoccer\statsbomb.py in read_event(path_or_buf, related_event_df, shot_freeze_frame_df, tactics_lineup_df, warn)
    120         match_id = int(path_or_buf.url.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0])
    121     else:
--> 122         df = pd.read_json(path_or_buf, encoding='utf-8')
    123         match_id = int(os.path.basename(path_or_buf)[:-5])
    124 

E:\py\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    205                 else:
    206                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 207             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    208 
    209         return cast(F, wrapper)

E:\py\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

E:\py\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, encoding_errors, lines, chunksize, compression, nrows, storage_options)
    588         convert_axes = True
    589 
--> 590     json_reader = JsonReader(
    591         path_or_buf,
    592         orient=orient,

E:\py\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression, nrows, storage_options, encoding_errors)
    673                 raise ValueError("nrows can only be passed if lines=True")
    674 
--> 675         data = self._get_data_from_filepath(filepath_or_buffer)
 676         self.data = self._preprocess_data(data)
    677 

E:\py\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py in _get_data_from_filepath(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    710             or file_exists(filepath_or_buffer)
    711         ):
--> 712             self.handles = get_handle(
    713                 filepath_or_buffer,
    714                 "r",

E:\py\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    606 
    607     # open URLs
--> 608     ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
    609         path_or_buf,
    610         encoding=encoding,

E:\py\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in _get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode, storage_options)
    393     if not is_file_like(filepath_or_buffer):
    394         msg = f"Invalid file path or buffer object type: {type(filepath_or_buffer)}"
--> 395         raise ValueError(msg)
    396 
    397     return IOArgs(

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'requests_cache.models.response.CachedResponse'>
```

hoping someone can help me see exactly where pandas is struggling and what I can do to fix it? Thanks

Comment: The error implies that you're using the [`requests-cache`](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/v0.9.3/reference.html) module, and `response` is a cached response rather than the actual response text.

Comment: How would i go about disabling that module? I've not loaded it so unsure why it would be getting used

Comment: I can't think of why you would be getting it if you didn't import it.

Comment: bizarre. The only imported were pandas, statsbombpy, mplsoccer and requests. It appears to have been imported with pandas, as i uninstalled requests_cache, tried to run the code again and all of a sudden it wasnt recognising pandas

Comment: From all I can find, `requests_cache` is supposed to be transparent. I'm not sure why the object is showing up explicitly there.